# Machine Learning Using Scikit-Learn & SVM

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

Load popular digits dataset from `sklearn.datasets` module and assign it to variable digits.

Split `digits.data` into two sets names `X_train` and `X_test`. Also, split digits.target into two sets `Y_train` and `Y_test`.

Hint: Use `train_test_split()` method from `sklearn.model_selection`; set `random_state` to 30; and perform stratified sampling.
Build an SVM classifier from `X_train` set and `Y_train` labels, with default parameters. Name the model as `svm_clf`.

Evaluate the model accuracy on the testing data set and print its score.
I used the following code:

```py
import sklearn.datasets as datasets
import sklearn.model_selection as ms
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


digits = datasets.load_digits();
X = digits.data
y = digits.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=30)
    
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)

from sklearn.svm import SVC
svm_clf = SVC().fit(X_train, y_train)
print(svm_clf.score(X_test,y_test))
```

I got the below output.

```
(1347,64)
(450,64)
0.4088888888888889
```

But I am not able to pass the test. Can someone help with what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the stratified sampling requirement; modify your split to include it:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=30, stratify=y)
```

Check the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).